# Using Javascript /jquery displaying a single file in a fly out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a player that will play audio on the site. It will play music randomly and display only play/pause? are there any good javascript or jquery plugin/api?

What is the best way to display a single music filefrom a list of files on a flyout on hover? it will have the option to display filename and download option.

Any examples would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of any preexisting libraries that handle this, but it wouldn't be hard to accomplish with [HTML5's `<audio>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp). You can control it using the `play()` and `pause()` methods. Check out [HTMLMediaElement on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement) for how to interact with the element.

You could use [JQueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com/) to create some sort of a dialogue for presentation.

Comment: Nope! I don't think any versions of IE below 9 have any HTML5 support. You could do a check if the element is supported, and if not have a small hidden flash player that utilizes the same controls... I'm not too sure about that one.